# For loop - count, wait with counter, keep counting

Tags: javascript

The for loop is to go through all elements and call another function.

**Example:**
The for loop should call the function 5 times, then wait 20 seconds and then call the next 5 elements. Until all elements have been called once. During the 20 seconds, the counter should show how many seconds remain until the next 5 elements are processed.

```js
function myCounter(counter) {
  var interval = setInterval(function() {
      counter--;
    sec = Math.floor(counter % 60);  
    min = Math.floor(counter/60);

    sec = (sec < 10)?'0'+sec:sec;
    min = (min < 10)?'0'+min:min;

      $('#counter').html(min+':'+sec);
      if (counter == 0) {
          clearInterval(interval);
          return counter;
      }
  }, 1000);
}

var x = 1;
for (i=0; i<=50; i++){

  // if x < 5 then the next 5 elements
  // call the external function
  $('.check').html(i);

 //if x > 4 show the counter and wait to 0
  if(x > 5){
    myCounter(20);
    x=0;
  }
  x++;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="counter"></p>
<p id="msg">Mache was <span class="check"></span></p>
```

Comment: What is the question? What does go wrong?

Comment: Use recursion and a setTimeout(). What happens now is that the entire for loop will run normally until it gets to x = 5. Then the rest of the loop will queue 45 intervals, which will each try to update the label 20 times. So instead of a for loop, use a function that changes x. Then have the function either directly calls itself, or setTimeout() itself to run again in 20 seconds. Updating the label can be hooked to setTimeout and just have the next setTimeout() cancel the previous interval so you do not have to do time calculations.

Comment: As @Shilly wrote `Recursion` along with `setTimeout` could also provide a solid answer. The same can also apply using `Recursion`, `Promise` and `setInterval`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To execute something 5 times every 20 seconds and count down in between, try setting up your intervals like this:

```js
var MAX_GLOBAL_I = 50;
var GLOBAL_I = 0;
setInterval(doSomething, 20000);
doSomething();

function doSomething(){
 for(var i = 0; i < 5 && GLOBAL_I < MAX_GLOBAL_I; i++){
  console.log("i: " + i);
  console.log("GLOBAL_I: " + GLOBAL_I);
  console.log("----------");
  
  GLOBAL_I++;
 }
 if(GLOBAL_I < MAX_GLOBAL_I){
  runTimer(20);
 }
}

function runTimer(secs){
 logTime(secs);
 var timer = setInterval(function(){
  --secs == 0 ? clearInterval(timer) : logTime(secs);
 }, 1000);
}

function logTime(currentSecs){
 console.log(currentSecs);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use something like this example below using `Promise`.

```
const sleep = (elements, sleepTime, callback) => {
  let secs = sleepTime / 1000;
  let i = 0;
  let counter = 5;
  let elms = elements.splice(0, counter);
  if (elms.length <= 5) {
    counter = elms.length;
  }
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    while (i < counter) {
      if (elms[i] !== undefined) {
        console.log("this is element: " + elms[i]);
      }
      i++;
      if (i == counter) {
        let logger = setInterval(() => {
          console.log("waiting for " + secs + " seconds");
          secs--;
          if (secs == 0) {
            clearInterval(logger);
            if (elements.length == 0) {
              if(typeof callback == "function") {
                  callback();
              } 
              resolve(true);
            } else {
              sleep(elements, sleepTime, callback);
            }
          }
        }, 1000);
      }
    }
  });
}
```

**Usage**

```
const chel = [...]; // your elements are here
const onFinish = () => {
    alert("...finished!");
}
alert("Starting...!");
sleep(chel, 20000, onFinish); // or sleep(chel, 20000);
```

You can try this out by running the snippet below *(sleepTime is set to 5 seconds)*.

```js
const sleep = (elements, sleepTime, callback) => {
  let secs = sleepTime / 1000;
  let i = 0;
  let counter = 5;
  let elms = elements.splice(0, counter);
  if (elms.length <= 5) {
    counter = elms.length;
  }
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    while (i < counter) {
      if (elms[i] !== undefined) {
        console.log("this is element: " + elms[i]);
      }
      i++;
      if (i == counter) {
        let logger = setInterval(() => {
          console.log("waiting for " + secs + " seconds");
          secs--;
          if (secs == 0) {
            clearInterval(logger);
            if (elements.length == 0) {
              if (typeof callback == "function") {
                callback();
              }
              resolve(true);
            } else {
              sleep(elements, sleepTime, callback);
            }
          }
        }, 1000);
      }
    }
  });
}
const chel = ["H - Hydrogen", "He - Helium", "Li - Lithium", "Be - Beryllium", "B - Boron", "C - Carbon", "N - Nitrogen", "O - Oxygen", "F - Fluorine", "Ne - Neon", "Na - Sodium", "Mg - Magnesium", "Al - Aluminium", "Si - Silicon", "P - Phosphorus", "S - Sulfur", "Cl - Chlorine", "Ar - Argon", "K - Potassium", "Ca - Calcium", "Sc - Scandium", "Ti - Titanium", "V - Vanadium", "Cr - Chromium", "Mn - Manganese", "Fe - Iron", "Co - Cobalt", "Ni - Nickel", "Cu - Copper", "Zn - Zinc", "Ga - Gallium", "Ge - Germanium", "As - Arsenic", "Se - Selenium", "Br - Bromine", "Kr - Krypton", "Rb - Rubidium", "Sr - Strontium", "Y - Yttrium", "Zr - Zirconium", "Nb - Niobium", "Mo - Molybdenum", "Tc - Technetium", "Ru - Ruthenium", "Rh - Rhodium", "Pd - Palladium", "Ag - Silver", "Cd - Cadmium", "In - Indium", "Sn - Tin", "Sb - Antimony", "Te - Tellurium", "I - Iodine", "Xe - Xenon", "Cs - Caesium", "Ba - Barium", "La - Lanthanum", "Ce - Cerium", "Pr - Praseodymium", "Nd - Neodymium", "Pm - Promethium", "Sm - Samarium", "Eu - Europium", "Gd - Gadolinium", "Tb - Terbium", "Dy - Dysprosium", "Ho - Holmium", "Er - Erbium", "Tm - Thulium", "Yb - Ytterbium", "Lu - Lutetium", "Hf - Hafnium", "Ta - Tantalum", "W - Tungsten", "Re - Rhenium", "Os - Osmium", "Ir - Iridium", "Pt - Platinum", "Au - Gold", "Hg - Mercury", "Tl - Thallium", "Pb - Lead", "Bi - Bismuth", "Po - Polonium", "At - Astatine", "Rn - Radon", "Fr - Francium", "Ra - Radium", "Ac - Actinium", "Th - Thorium", "Pa - Protactinium", "U - Uranium", "Np - Neptunium", "Pu - Plutonium", "Am - Americium", "Cm - Curium", "Bk - Berkelium", "Cf - Californium", "Es - Einsteinium", "Fm - Fermium", "Md - Mendelevium", "No - Nobelium", "Lr - Lawrencium", "Rf - Rutherfordium", "Db - Dubnium", "Sg - Seaborgium", "Bh - Bohrium", "Hs - Hassium", "Mt - Meitnerium", "Ds - Darmstadtium", "Rg - Roentgenium", "Cn - Copernicium", "Nh - Nihonium", "Fl - Flerovium", "Mc - Moscovium", "Lv - Livermorium", "Ts - Tennessine", "Og - Oganesson"];


const onFinish = () => {
  alert("...finished!");
}
alert("Starting...!");
sleep(chel, 5000, onFinish);
```

Answer (score 0):

As noted in my comment, I would use the interval to update the label and a timeout for handling 5 elements. Once 5 have been handled, we wait `timeout` milliseconds until we handle the next 5. Keep in mind that intervals and timeouts are not exact. And that updating the counter visually also takes time.

If you need more control over the timings and/or want to sync the label to the refresh rate, look into `requestAnimationFrame()` and the `performance` object.

```js
// setup
const elements = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20 ];
const label = document.querySelector( '#timer ');
const timeout = 5000;
// we need variables to track the timer and the element we're handling 
let timer = null;
let index = 0;
let length = elements.length;
// handle elements until 5 have been handled
// then set a timeout to handle the next 5 in ${const timeout} seconds
const handle_five = () => {
  const element = elements[ index ];
  if ( element !== undefined ) {
    // do something with the element
    console.log( 'handling element', element, ' at index ', index );
    index += 1;
    if ( index < length ) {
      if ( index % 5 === 0 ) {
        run_timer();
        setTimeout( handle_five, timeout );
        console.log( '--- finished 5 ---' );
      }
      else handle_five();
    }
  }
};
// if we are waiting 20 seconds, we render a timer
const run_timer = () => {
  let count = timeout / 1000;
  timer = setInterval(() => {
    label.innerHTML = count;
    count -= 1;
    if ( !count ) {
      clearInterval( timer );
      label.innerHTML = '';
    }
  }, 1000 );
};
// start handling the elements*/
handle_five();
```

```html
<label id="timer"></label>
```